# formular for sum of column in a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I have a trivial problem. I need to create a vector, which has the sum of the columns in a AxB matrix. What would be the mathematical formula for that?

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need to write down a formular, for a vektor which has the sum of all column. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Hint: multiply the matrix from the left with a certain row vecter.

Comment: @Milten don't you mean column vector from the right?

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki I don't believe I do, no. Unless you transpose the matrix first.

Comment: If I multiply a matrix from the left with a row vector, I get a linear combination of the rows of the matrix. But we want a linear combination of the columns if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The following examples might be helpful.

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
&=\begin{pmatrix}a+b+c\\d+e+f\end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{pmatrix}
&=\begin{pmatrix}a+d&b+e&c+f\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: thank you, that is something I was looking for

Comment: @DChaka: You're welcome!